# Median Filter in Code Composer Studio

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a median filter for a 1D signal but I could not get the output from Code Composer Studio to be the same as Matlab. Please show me where my mistakes are.

```
#include<stdio>
#include<math.h>
#include<signal.h>

void medianfilter(short*signal, int signalLength, short* output, int windowSize)
{
    int i,j,k;

    for (i=2; i < signalLength - 2; i++)
    {
        float window[5];
        for (j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            window[j] = signal[i-2+j];
        }

        for (j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            window[j] = signal[i - 2 + j];
        }
    }

    // Order elements (only half of them)
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        //   Find position of minimum element
        int min = j;
        for (k = j + 1; k < 5; k++)
        {
            if (window[k] < window[min])
            min = k;
        }

        // Put found minimum element in its place
        float temp = window[j];
        window[j] = window[min];
        window[min] = temp;
    }

    // Get result - the middle element
    output[i - 2] = window[2];
}
```

Comment: Please do not post the code as image, upload your code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The problem *might* be due to the fact that the scope of the `window[]` array is limited to the first `for()` loop in your function, so there is no way of telling what data you're accessing from `window[]` later on. Is there a global array called `window[]` too? Does this even compile? Why have you put a semicolon after each `#include` statement? Why does your code contain five opening braces (`{`) but six closing braces (`}`)? Please provide a [mcve] as requested.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function that demonstrates how the actual results differ from what's expected. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].